# Hosting Laravel Project

Tags: laravel

Am new to Laravel, I just finished an eCommerce site. I don't know how to host it, what to remove before hosting it. I need help on how deploy Laravel. I have search through google tutorials yet I still could not find what am looking for. Aside that, I need a free domain name and hosting site to test it before hosting.

Comment: Check out [Forge](https://forge.laravel.com), created by Taylot Otwell, Laravel's creator. You can also watch [the Laracasts series on Forge](https://laracasts.com/series/server-management-with-forge).

Comment: You should try Cloudways. With Cloudways you can easily deploy your Laravel application on DigitalOcean, Linode, Vultr, AWS, GCE in just one click.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a vps, it will be much more secure, but you can always use shared hosting websites such as byethost, x10hosting, 000webhost, they will be less secure but can still get the job done.

Comment: I appreciate. the problem is that i don't even know where to start from am totally a babe to this business. Can I get videos on how to do it? iloopchannel@gmail.com or abraham9193@gmail.com. Thanks

Comment: Check this link out http://novate.co.uk/deploy-laravel-5-on-shared-hosting-from-heart-internet/